# AlarmManager not stopping or crashing

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I'm trying to figure out how the AlarmManager works, I've made this app with a recurring alarm, but it behaves erratically. After it runs once, trying to check crashes the app, or trying to cancel it no longer works. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
private Intent intentxx;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent service = new Intent(context, SampleSchedulingService.class);

    startWakefulService(context, service);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    intentxx = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
    intentxx.putExtra("timer", "timer1");
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentxx, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 2, alarmIntent);

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    if (alarmMgr != null) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        alarmIntent.cancel();
    }

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public boolean checkAlarm(Context context) {
    boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentxx, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

    return alarmUp;
}
```

Edit: 
After it triggers once, I try to check() and it crashes giving this error. And as I said, I can't even cancel() it anymore, it keeps running on and on.

```
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:487)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:472)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.example.android.scheduler.SampleAlarmReceiver.checkAlarm(SampleAlarmReceiver.java:143)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.example.android.scheduler.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:61)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2640)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1171)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:630)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:200)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
07-04 01:19:20.244: E/AndroidRuntime(29863):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hard to make any statements without error messages or stack traces.

Comment: It says that you have a NullPointerException in your checkAlarm() method, more specifically, when you call the PendingIntent.getBroadcast() method. Try checking whether any of the objects that you pass the PendingIntent.getBroadcast() method are null (context or intentxx)

Comment: Turns out the original android sample is bugged, and after its first run you can't cancel it. I've only changed the calendar and setRepeating to every 2 minutes, instead of every day.

As for the NullPointer in my checking method, it's most likely something related to that, the intent or the pendingintent not matching.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this version works ok. Turns out the pendingIntent has to be created every time.

```
public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, SampleSchedulingService.class);

        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 1, alarmIntent);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        alarmIntent.cancel();

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public boolean checkAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

        return alarmUp;
    }
}
```